# Hide an element if it has two particular classes or only one of the clases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to hide an HTML element if it has both classes or only the `.more-options` class, but if it only has the `.show-required` class do nothing.

This is what I have

HTML:

```
<tr class="show-required">
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="show-required more-options">
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="more-options">
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

I want it to only hide/show the second and third `<tr>` and leave the other one alone.
Also to clarify it does need to have **both classes** or just `.more-options` for later code.

any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

I need this to be done with javascript/Jquery

Comment: "... it does need to have both classes or just .more-options" - this is basically the same as saying "Hide everything has .more-options" regardless of whether it has another class.

Comment: @RyanKinal, also though that at first, but "for later code" seems he may add other conditions later...

Comment: I use the ".show-required" later and if I only hide ".more options" then it does not work. It is for validation so some need to be required and some not.

Comment: @JoshYoung: Define "it does not work."

Comment: I am using a choice field to show or hide more form elements. All elements that will be shown or hidden need ".more-options", but some also need to be validated, thus adding ".show-required". It looks to see if ".show-required" is visible and if it is then validate. I am using an If-Else statement to show/hide using .show() and .hide(). If i use the selector "$('.more-options')" then it will try to validate the fields if they are hidden as well as visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple class selector:

```
.class1.class2
{

}
```

Multiple selectors are separated by comma:

```
.class1.class2,
.class1
{

}
```

So, in your case:

```
.more-options, 
.show-required.more-options
{
    //style
}
```

**EDIT**

As required, jquery selector uses css selectors, so:

```
$(".more-options, .show-required.more-options").show(); // or hide
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include a multiclass selector, normal cascade is enough:

```css
.more-options {
    display: none;
}
.show-required {
    display: table-row;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Volker_E/3htzrhLb/

Answer (score 0):

```
.more-options, 
.show-required.more-options {
  display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lh0b1ten/1/

Answer (score 0):

This seems too simple, but it should do what you say.

```
$('.more-options').hide();
```

Your requirements make it sound like you want anything with `more-options` to be hidden, even if they have another class on them. Since CSS selectors ignore classes that aren't mentioned, this will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("tr").each(
    function(){
             if($(this).hasClass("more-options")){
                $(this).hide();
             }
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cx4a9L55/8/)